# Kbmmw. Time out message "Anonymous user not authorized"

Tags: delphi

I made a new topic about my issue.

KIM told\

> Anonymous requests typically means that it does not find a
>   username/password not a token in the clients request. Remember the
>   Token you get on your first request should be reused for all
>   subsequent requests by all client code (all kbmMWSimpleClient,
>   kbmMWClientQuery, kbmMWClientResolver etc). On way to centralize that
>   is to put a TkbmMWSimpleClient on the datamodule and specify all the
>   client query components to use this simple client instance as a
>   template. Then as the first thing before anything else in your client
>   application, make an initial "login" request call via the
>   simpleclient.

I changed ServerSideQueryAllClick on the client app. I copied Token from server side to client Edit1.text.

```
procedure TForm1.btnNamedServerSideQueryAllClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
     // Gets all records from server event table.
     If Length(Trim(Edit1.Text)) > 0 then
        Begin
          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Disconnect;

          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Username:= CB1.Text; // Login -> Franz
          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Password:= CB2.Text; // Password -> FranzPassword

          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Token := Edit1.Text; // Token from server
          kbmMWSimpleClient1.Connect;

        End;

     if qServerSide.Active then qServerSide.Close;

     // Use named query.
     qServerSide.Query.Text:='@ALL_EVENTS';
     qServerSide.Open;
end;
```

It  dowsn't work.

How to make relogin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization demo shows how the client has a simpleclient that is used as template for all the client query components (by setting their Client property to point at the simpleclient instance).
When setting the token, you specifically do not want to set the username or password, and similarly if you are setting username and password, do not set the token.

Also make sure that qServerSide.Client points on your simpleclient.
Doing that you generally only need to setup username/password once on the simpleclient before anything is opened, then for example open the query component, after which the simpleclient.token value will automatically have been updated from the server with the assigned login token.